# Android is not recognizing a variable that has already been declared

Tags: android, binding

This file shows that a hook variable called readBtnButton was created, which receives the readdataBtn variable (name of a button).
When the binding calls readBtnButton, the readBtnButton variable is not recognized, as you can see in the link:
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/8n9Bb88

You can see the binding has been declared in build.gradle: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/DBFRJKQ

biding is an object from the class called ActivityReaddataBinding:
https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/j9Pf9uA

Please, what to do to fix this error?

Comment: The binding object does not use your variable names. It uses the IDs from the layout XML for its variables; e.g., `binding.readdataBtn.setOnClickListener(...`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mike.